# SQL Using a Select Grant in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm using Oracle 11g R2.  Our setup is an ODS and a Data Warehouse.

I need to write a query which joins tables from the ODS to tables in the DW.  My Query is fine however i am getting an error "table or view does not exist".  I've been told this is because i need to use a Grant Select on my query to allow the DW to 'see' the tables in the ODS.  I've looked online but my attempts to integrate it just isn't working.

I've been using

```
grant select on ODS_Product to DW;
grant select on ODS_History to DW;
```

I get the script output saying grant succeeded but then when i go to the DW SQL worksheet and execute my query i get the error.

Anyone able to advise/or provide an example?

Comment: Make sure you qualify table[s] with schema name if it's not default schema for user.  For instance, `SELECT * FROM  schemaName. ODS_Product`. Or create public synonyms (not very good idea, it's rather a quick workaround)

Comment: Thats great, i ran my query again with the schema qualification:
ODS.ODS_Product
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These need to be fully qualified grants executed either by the owner of the tables or a database user whom has the "grant select" privilege.

As an example, a user logged in to the schema owning the ods tables will need to execute this:

grant select on ods_schema.ODS_Product to DW;

grant select on ods_schema.ODS_History to DW;

Comment: You'd only need to qualify the table names if you *weren't* logged in as (or with current schema set to) the table owner (and had the privs to do that). The issue is with qualifying the `select`, not the `grant`.

Comment: I assumed that the person's query was being fully qualified (e.g.   ods_schema.ODS_Product).  You are correct.